# C - writing to an array of structs - unmodifiable lvalue

Tags: c

I have a struct defined by:

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[CANDY_NAME_LEN];
    bool vegan;
} candy;
```

I define an array of size 10 of these structs:

```
const candy candy_db[NUM_OF_CANDIES];
```

and try to fill the array:

```
strcpy_s(candy_db[0].name, sizeof(candy_db[0].name), "Apple");
candy_db[0].vegan = true;
```

but setting true to the bool field of the first element (or any element) in the array gives me an error:
expression must be a modifiable lvalue.

what is the problem?

thanks

Comment: You give const, this is OK. Wrong when `strcpy_s` doen't give warning

Comment: const means read only, immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const candy candy_db[NUM_OF_CANDIES];`

You've defined your array as `const`, so none of its elements can be modified.

Comment: but the exercise instructions says to define a constant array of "candies", so how can I do that?

Comment: You could do that by initializing the array with data imediately, not `strcpy` but an initializer:
`const candy candy_db[NUM_OF_CANDIES] = { {"Apply", true} };`

Comment: so when defining a const, the only way to fill it is when initializing?
and how would I modify it after that? I tried using pointers but my syntax was wrong with the bool field of the struct

Comment: That's exactly the point of a const - it's a constant, it's unchanging data.
If you need to modify it later, don't define it as a const...